# Couldn't split this string with regex properly

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I got this

`'','','{12345678},{87654321}','lk12l1k2l12lkl12lkl121l2lk12'`

trying to match it using `'(.*?)',|'(.*?)'`

It successfully got my 4 chunks

```
''
''
'{12345678},{87654321}'
'lk12l1k2l12lkl12lkl121l2lk12'
```

But I am trying to use the same regex in split... it doesn't like it. :(

```
var str = "'','','{12345678},{87654321}','lk12l1k2l12lkl12lkl121l2lk12'";
str.split(/'(.*?)',|'(.*?)'/);
```

Any idea...? ugh.

Comment: What does "doesn't like it" mean?

Comment: It splitted incorrectly, instead of 4, is getting 12, basically it considering `'` as 1, also `,` as 1 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `split`?

You can get your four chunks with `match`:

```
var chunks = str.match(/'[^']*'/g);
```

Comment: Thank you master, is it possible to remove the single quotes using the match at the same time?

Comment: For IE > 8: `str.match(/'[^']*'/g).map(function(v) { return v.slice(1, -1)})`

Answer (score 0):

Is the `split()` neccessary?

You could always get the information between the quotes using `match()`.

```
test.match(/'(.*?)'/g)
```

Test it please.

Comment: Nope, tried something similar before I post, your solution messes up with the inner comma.

Comment: I changed my answer. Please check it out and let me know.